# How to determine the display object hierarchy an event will capture/bubble through?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3, events

In Actionscript 3 is there any way to determine the precise display object hierarchy an event will traverse through when dispatched from a given object?  The object is not necessarily a display object.

Although I could imagine this actually being useful somehow, in my particular case it is a learning exercise.  I'm trying to master the event system in flash and have some locations where I'm very curious what path an event will take when I dispatch it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is sort of. Events aren't limited to DisplayObjects, and when they are triggered by DisplayObjects, they don't always follow the same pattern -- the Event may very based on what type of DisplayObject and whether the event was triggered programmatically (through dispatchEvent) or natively (by a mouseClick). It may also vary based on whether bubbling is enabled or not and if it is a custom event.  A Loader's complete event, for example, does not make sense to propagate to parent objects, even though Loader is a display object.

If you're trying to figure out the parents of the object which dispatched an event, then you'll want something like this:

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.DisplayObject;
import flash.display.DisplayObjectContainer;
myDispatcher.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler );

function clickHandler( event:MouseEvent ):void
{
    // event.currentTarget is the object which you're listening to.
    // event.target is the object which actually dispatched the event
    // (if you're listening to a MovieClip and a button inside it is clicked,
    // target will refer to the button, currentTarget the MovieClip)
    var ancestry:Vector.<DisplayObjectContainer> = getAncestry( event.currentTarget as DisplayObject );
    // do somethign with all of the parents.

}

// this function takes a DisplayObject and returns all of its ancestor objects 
// all the way to the root as a Vector.
function getAncestry( obj:DisplayObject ):Vector.<DisplayObjectContainer>
{
    var par:Object = obj.parent;
    var ancestry:Vector.<DisplayObjectContainer> = new Vector.<DisplayObjectContainer>();
    while( par )
    {
        par = par.parent;
        ancestry.push( par as DisplayObject );
        if( par == root ) break;//sometimes the root has a parent.
    }
    return ancestry;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is absolutely a way. Flash has a few convenient functions/properties that could facilitate this.

Because all flash objects that extend** another class, like DisplayObject, have a parent property, you can simply write:

```
import "flash.utils.getQualifiedClassName";

var bubblePath:String = "";

var parentObject:* = parent;
while( parentObject ) {
    bubblePath += getQualifiedClassName( parentObject ) + "\n";
    parentObject = parentObject.parent;
}

trace( bubblePath );
```

This will give you a string with the names of all the classes. I am not sure if that is what you are looking for in your experiment, but it shouldn't be difficult to modify output as necessary.

Comment: Import as a String? `All flash objects that expend another class, like DisplayObject`????

Comment: +1 for the approach.  The one thing I'd like to add is that if a class is not part of a display hierarchy; the events is dispatches will not have a capture or bubble phase.  And @cwallenpoole seems correct; I believe the import statement should have no quotes around the class name.